# how can I modify the "any" function to become more like "all" in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

Right now I have this piece of code: `filter (any ('elem' "abc")) [String]`. This checks to see if an element from [String] contains 'a' or 'b' or 'c', which returns as true, but this isn't exactily what I need. I want to see if it contains 'a' and 'b' and 'c'. the "all" function won't work because it would check if everything was 'a' or 'b' or 'c', which means something like "abcd" would return false which I don't want. Ty.

Answer (score 2):

You should swap the `"abc"` and `"abcdefg" part:

```
all (`elem` "abcdefg") "abc"
```

this thus checks if `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` are all elements of the `"abcdefg"` string.

Or you can filter a list of strings with:

```
filter (\x -> all (`elem` x) "abc") ["abcdef", "acdef"]
```

Comment: I can't do that in this case, outside of this example the real code is ` filter (any (`elem` a)) b`, b is a List so I can't switch them. if you know a way around this that would be very helpful

Comment: @Amber: a list of *what*?

Comment: @Amber: can you please edit the question with the real problem: this might be the XY problem.

Comment: Changed the problem, hope that helps.

Comment: @Amber: you can work with a lambda expression.

Comment: not really, i'm pretty new to haskell

Comment: I could google it though

Comment: @Amber: see update.

Comment: If `filter (any (elem a)) b` typechecks at all, then `a` and `b` _must_ have the same type.

Comment: well a is a string and b is a [string] and it works. ghci> filter (any (`elem` "abc")) ["a","abc","afdslkj","k"]
["a","abc","afdslkj"]